# WCF RIA Services and communicating via SSL

Tags: silverlight, ssl, ria

I have a simple Silverlight application that use WCF RIA Services to communicate with the ASP.NET application on my web server. By default I assume that this communication is plain and not encrypted in any way.

How do you request it use SSL or some other method to ensure that all data via the WCF RIA Service is secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a domain service you can specify in the `EnableClientAccess` attribute that only secured transport is allowed.

ie.

```
[EnableClientAccess( RequiresSecureEndpoint = true )]
```