# RIA Services and SSL by configuration?

Tags: silverlight, ssl, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386016/wcf-ria-services-and-communicating-via-ssl) I need to set an attribute in code to get SSL encryption for my RIA service calls. Is there no way to do this with a configuration file?

(I currently use Visual Studio 2008 and Silverlight 3.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VS2008 + Silverlight 3 but with VS2010 and Silverlight 4 you can set it through web.config.

You can use the [behavior.serviceMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) tag to set https enabled.

e.g.

```
<behavior name="ReportServiceBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
</behavior>
```

You then set the security mode for any bindings, e.g.

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="webHttpBindingConf">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Are these settings not available in SL3?

Comment: With RIA Services the configuration file is empty. I now use SL4 but do not really see any changes. Did you actually do this or is your answer a guess on what it could be based on your WCF know-how? I am aware that these settings are possible with WCF, but too me it looks that this is not the case with RIA...

Comment: I added these settings into the Web.config file of the project hosting my RIA Service.